# Local admin login fails "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed" on Windows 10

Tags: active-directory, windows-10

After joining a 2019 (2016 equivalent) domain, domain logins are successful however local admin accounts fail with "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed."

I created a new local admin account with my domain credentials and verified this error continues, however, logins to the domain even uncached credentials succeed. What further troubleshooting steps can I perform? This kind of seems the opposite of what people typically are trying to do of getting into a machine without local admin access.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a complication to the problem, AD trust relation failures can generally be fixed using the `Test-ComputerSecureChannel` Powershell cmdlet.

From an elevated Powershell prompt, run:

```
Test-ComputerSecureChannel
```

If it reports that the channel has failed: `false` Fix the channel by running:

```
 Test-ComputerSecureChannel -Repair
```

Failing that, you may need to unjoin the computer from the domain, then rejoin it, which can be done with either the System applet in the control panel, or the `Remove-Computer` and `Add-Computer` cmdlets from Powershell.

Comment: Hey Davidw, what do I do if it returns false? I tried -verbose and got `VERBOSE: The attempt to repair the secure channel between the local computer and the domain <placeholder> has failed.`

Comment: You may need to remove and rejoin the computer to the domain.

Comment: Double checking, you're running the repair from an elevated prompt, correct?

Comment: Yes it is an elevated prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two problems:

1. The fact that `Test-ComputerSecureChannel` returns `False` is one problem, but does not need to be solved to login with a local account. You have to solve this, to not run into trouble when logging in with domain accounts though.
2. To login with a local account (no matter if it is a member of the local `Administrators` group), you have to tell your machine that you want to authenticate against the local user database and not against AD, which will be the default on domain-joined computers. You can force a local authentication by prefixing your username by `.\` or by `COMPUTERNAME\`:

   ```
   .\localuser
   ```

   or

   ```
   COMPUTERNAME\localuser
   ```

Comment: That is what is odd, I receive the error message when logging in with the local credential via the method `COMPUTERNAME\localuser` and even though `Test-ComputerSecureChannel` returns false - I am able to login with an uncached domain credential.

Comment: @phillhocking Does your computer name match your domain name by any chance?